# Ipsecurity restriction set on at a file level through UI is not reflecting in the applicationhost.config or web.config

Tags: iis-7.5

**Problem1 :**
I have a asp.net 4 website hosted on IIS 7.5. I have a file which would only have access from a set of IP addresses and needs anonymous access.

1. Followed the steps listed in http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/ipSecurity
2. Enabled the **IP and Domain restriction** role
3. Selected the file where the restriction needed to be applied. Added the restriction through the UI.
4. Restarted the webserver

I was assuming an entry like

```
<location path="WEBSITE/FILEPATH">
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
            <add ipAddress="192.168.100.1" />
            <add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
         </ipSecurity>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

in my **applicationhost.config** file. Can't find it.

Tried looking for the entries in the web.config of the WEBSITE. Not there either.

**Question:**
Where does IIS Manager save this information ?

**Problem2:** I try to add the above **`<location>`** xlm in my web.config file. Try to access the file through the browser and get a 500 response code. I try to access the IP and Domain restriction module through IIS Manager and i get an error which says

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. 
This level happens when the section is locked at a parent level.
Locking is either by default(overrideModeDefault="Deny") 
or set explicitly by a location tab with overrrideMode="Deny" 
or the legacy allowOverride="false"
```

After some googling i open applicationHost.config and change the override behaviour of ipSecurity tag to

```
<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
<!-- other stuff here removed for brevity -->
<section name="ipSecurity" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
</sectionGroup>
```

After doing this i get the same error.
Out of sheer frustration and desperation i also do this

```
<location path="" overrrideMode="Allow">
<system.webServer>
<modules>
<add name="IpRestrictionModule" lockItem="false"/>
</modules>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

I'm sure i'm missing something really simple.

I hope i was able to put my question across clearly.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge these settings can be configured only at a folder level, not at a file level. In the IIS management snap-in there is no option to select a file, only folders and websites are selectable before choosing this option.

Edit: I've found what you've done and it IS actually possible to do this (to my surprise  the configuration manager can even create  elements in web.config files in subfolders).

The configuration is stored in ApplicationHost.config in C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config:

```
<location path="apixaban.de/test/test.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <ipSecurity>
                <add ipAddress="172.100.16.11" allowed="true" />
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Note : this is a direct child of the "configuration" node.

Comment: [answer]
* Select the folder where the file is
* Click the content View tab at the bottom
* Right Click the file you are interested in and click Switch to Features view.
* You can now see the file in the left tree navigation allowing you to do what i say.

Comment: So you are saying you see the location entry in your applciationHost.config when you add the ip restriction through IIS manager ?[ask]

Comment: Yes; I've made the modification on a dev server and the configuration snipped in my answer is what the result was in the ApplicationHost.config.
Are you sure you're viewing the right config file? Can you try setting this at the folder level? What's the timestamp of you ApplicationHost.config file?

Answer (score 4):

Try opening the file in Notepad or wordpad instead of Notepad++ or Editplus on 64bit OS. Changes made through IIS UI are not reflected if you open the file in Notepad++ or Editplus.
There are other other issues related to editing and viewing the file in Notepad++.
http://www.cosnetics.co.uk/articles/cannot-manually-edit-applicationhost.config/

Comment: This strangely works. Editing with Notepad++ doesn't commit the changes. Even when saved. If you open it in plain old notepad it shows the old version.

Comment: The issue here is that Notepad++ is a 32-bit application. By default, the WOW64 layer of Windows redirects any read/write attempts to system32 folder to the SysWOW64 folder. So Notepad++ does actually write the file, but to a different location. *Workaround:* Copy the file to your desktop, edit it, copy it back, restart IIS.